# Show text on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is meant to show riddle then you click the button and it shows the answer

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Riddles</title>
<link href="/css/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" />
<link href="/style.css" type="Cascading style sheet/text" />
</head>
<body>
```

This is the links

```
<li>What did the Robot say to the gas pump</li>
<script type="javascript/text">
     function unhide (){
     style(document).ready
     var hid = ("div.exp")
          if (true) hid.css("visibility",hidden);
            hid({
            visibility:visible
            });
     }
 </script>
<button onclick="unhide()">Show Answer</button>
<div class="exp">
    <p class="and">Take your finger out of your ear and listen to me</p>
</div>
<!--take your finger out of your ear and listen to me-->
```

style.css is

```
.exp{
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

Why is it not working?
Because it should work

I tried it many different ways

Comment: I say this gently, but I think you need to brush up on JavaScript syntax.

Comment: You need to work on your JS syntax. Its kinda mess right now

Comment: We can appreciate that you're trying, but there really isn't any way to meaningfully answer this without just trying to implement the whole thing for you.  Which, while possible, is unlikely to happen at Stack Overflow.  Your JavaScript code doesn't make much sense at all.  What I recommend is that you start smaller.  Pick one simple thing that you want your code to do and get that working first.  Once that's working, add the next feature.  And so on until you have your intended functionality.  We can help with any specific problems along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following code. I had to start from scratch, since your code was a bit confusing.

```js
function unhide() {
    var hid = document.getElementsByClassName("exp");
    // Emulates jQuery $(element).is(':hidden');
    if(hid[0].offsetWidth > 0 && hid[0].offsetHeight > 0) {
        hid[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>
.exp{visibility: hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="unhide()">Show Answer</button>
<div class="exp">
    <p class="and">Take your finger out of your ear and listen to me</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Just some recommendations.

- Is better if you use ids when you only want to modify one item.
- If you are starting, I believe that `jquery` could be easier to learn.
- Check your `javascript` syntax, as of now, it is a bit messy.

Comment: i know a bit but i mainly use css and html

Comment: Don’t worry, we all start somewhere. I would really recommend learning jquery though. Much easier for beginners. Please, let me know if you need something else.

Comment: i am trying to do was this [link](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/4cKNohk6Pv-6NpcUMN2eHLfQFaLYsQZY1PQotns2Aew/edit)

Comment: Ok, try the new changes. It should work now for sure :).

Comment: [this it](http://waders.tech/riddles.html) @alain cruz ya should work but it does not

Comment: Do you have more than one element using the exp class?

Comment: i might do not think so though, i checked a bit and i did not see it

Comment: So I added my answer into a code snippet. As you can see it runs as intended. If I may, it would be much easier if you add an id to your div. That way it is easier to handle. Please, let me know if this edit helped you out.

Comment: thanks it will work perfect. just wondering it should work backwards right?

Comment: Good to know I was of help! :)

Answer (score 10):

Another approach without javascript would be to use a [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) with a [`<summary>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) inside. Browsers will provide the interactivity.

```html
<details>
  <summary>What did the robot say to the gas pump?</summary>
  <p>Take your finger out of your ear and listen to me!</p>
</details>
```

Comment: that helped a lot